# ASP.NET API приложение с React на одном сервере

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Я хочу сделать веб-приложение. Клиентская часть на реакт, серверная часть - апишка на асп нет коре. Как мне это сделать ? Мне нужно,

1. Чтобы при разработке запускался 1 сервер под все(или пусть даже не 1, но чтоб автоматом запускал и фронт сервер, видел для этого есть UseSpa какой-то)
2. Чтоб потом можно было собрать фронт (npm) и чтоб все было одним приложением(видимо собрать через npm build и потом эти файлы чисто как статику раздавать), которое можно задеплоить.

Comment: Вам нужно SPA приложение, по сути где фронт пишется отдельно, бек отдельно, но публикуются вместе. Ну пример можно подглядеть у меня в пет проекте https://github.com/tym32167/battleyemanager хотя я не последние технологии использую. Я именно собираю фронт нодой и бек дотнетом, потом копирую собранный фронт в бек и запускаю. Сборка выглядит [примерно так](https://github.com/tym32167/battleyemanager/blob/master/content/installation.md) если надо на IIS поставить или можно развернуть это где то в докере.

Comment: Лично я использую разные инструменты для того, чтобы фронт писать и бек, но вот есть туториал от МС, где они все в одном делают [Учебник. Создание приложения ASP.NET Core с помощью React в Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022)

Comment: туториал на reactjs [здесь](https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html), на этом [гуглить за вас](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+and+asp.net+core) заканчиваю, дальше сами =)